# How can I resolve a Redo logfile blocksize catch 22?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Using Oracle Enterprise edition 19c.

In a test environment I created a physical machine running Windows 2022 server. Long story short, I have been working with RAID arrays. In between each iteration I shutdown the DB disable the services and move the database to another drive. After recreating the Array I move the data back and startup the services.

Unfortunately the arrays I am switching between have different sector sizes. One is 512 the other is 4096. When moving from a 4096 to 512 sector size I was able to set a parameter "_DISK_SECTOR_SIZE_OVERRIDE"=TRUE and open the database. I then created new logfiles which were created with 512 byte blocksize. I dropped the 4096 blocksize log files.

However when I do the reverse try to go from 512 to 4096, the same procedure does not work. It will not open the DB, with a ora-312, ora-27040 and osd-04001 errors.

In an attempt to open the DB I executed "recover database until cancel;" and now I must open the databased in resetlogs mode. When I do it returns Ora-00344 ora-27040 and osd-04001 errors.

When I try to switch redo logs without opening the DB it tells me the database isn't open.

How do I recover from this preferably without recreating everything?

**Note**

I was able to solve the issue by installing another hard drive with 512 byte sectors, shutdown the DB stop the services, copy the DB to the other drive. Re-letter the drive (D:<=>E:), startup the DB create new redo log files on the "C:" drive, drop the other redo log files. I then reversed everything putting the DB back on the RAID and left the redo log files on C:.

I will suggest to Oracle (spitting in the wind) the make they change the  "alter database open resetlogs" to not use the values in V$LOG, and fully recreate the log groups and files.

I did not post this as a solution because it didn't solve the issue I had, but it did allow me to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the database down, drop (or move out of the way) the problem online redo logs.

Using RMAN, recover to the last available archive log:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Jun 20 00:41:38 2019
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> startup mount;
ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area 2415917880 bytes
Fixed Size          8899384 bytes
Variable Size         520093696 bytes
Database Buffers     1879048192 bytes
Redo Buffers            7876608 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL>


RMAN> run
2> {
3> set until sequence 4;  <-- substitute appropriate "until" clause
4> restore database;
5> recover database;
6> alter database open resetlogs;
7> }
```

The recovery process recreates the online redo logs. Be sure and take another complete backup as soon as your database is back up.

Comment: Errors from RMAN command include;failure to restore no backup or copy of datafile 162 found to restore.

Comment: Ah. I may have assumed from your previous comment on recovery that you had a complete RMAN backup from which to restore. is that not the case? Can you go back to the 512-byte sector array and get things working there again? Then take a complete RMAN backup and try again.